# Which Solution is better in leetCode in terms of Runtime and Memory Usage?

Tags: java, memory, runtime

I know it might be a stupid question but how do i know which solution is better in leetCode

[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGm5H.png)

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "which solution is better in leetCode"? Does it give different scores based on runtime and memory usage?

Comment: I mean… it should tell you which is better. In *my* opinion a 50% speed increase with a minor bump in memory usage seems like a clear win.

Comment: i have submitted 2 solutions and it gave me the stats in the image above. but i don't think it gave me a better score

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Which is better" is always a matter of opinion.  In your particular application, is execution time or memory use more of a problem?  Then optimize for that aspect.

In terms of leetcode, I understand it's a sort of quiz, but for numbers that small, my response is "who cares?".  I don't care about an execution-time difference of 5 mS for an entire program (even though the faster saves ~30% of the runtime of the latter).  I don't care about a memory difference of half a megabyte for an entire program (and here the savings are of the order of 1%).

Now, if that code happens to be part of a large program where we're scaling up a million-fold, or something like that, **then** I'd care, possibly a lot.  But absent that information, it doesn't seem to matter. I'd favour optimizing for the time spent writing it -- programmers being more expensive than machine time.

If this particular leetcode test has time/space objectives, then it might matter there also. But you have not mentioned any such.